# Trouble speeding up arduino

Tags: pointers, arduino

I'm trying to speed up my Arduino code by direct writing to registers. I wrote a short test script, but it doesn't seem to do much. If I use the 'digitalWrite()' function I can see an output on the oscilloscope, but using this code it just stays 0.
I used [this link](https://garretlab.web.fc2.com/en/arduino/inside/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c/digitalWrite.html) as a reference. I can't quite grasp what I missed.

```
byte *outputRegister;
byte bitMask;

void setup() {
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  outputRegister = portOutputRegister(8);
  bitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(8);
}

void loop() {
  *outputRegister |= bitMask;
  delay(1);
  *outputRegister &= ~bitMask;
  delay(1);
}
```

EDIT: The `portOutRegister` should return the port where the output pins are set. The `digitalPinToBitmask` function returns a bitmask (something like 0b00000001 for the first pin on the respective port).
With some further testing, I concluded that the digitalWrite function doesn't seem to actually change the values in these registers, which does nothing more than confuse me.

Comment: delay(1)? try delay(1000)

Comment: Hard to say without see ```portOutputRegister``` and ```digitalPinToBitMask``` code

Comment: compare the result of `portOutRegister` to your expected value: Arduino Pin 8 on an atmega328 (uno/nano) is `PORTB`

Answer (score 0):

Arduino, if its Model = Uno, then it is ATmega-328 AVR, the best way to solve critical timing issues and achieve better execution times and code optimizations you should program via direct register modifications. That being said, use AVR-GCC, include and then do bit twiddling. Your code is not readable and hard to understand. 
IMO you should either write in C++ inside Arduino IDE >> slower but easier option, or
start programming outside IDE inC and directly the AVR, >> orders of magnitude performance increase. Get to know the AVR Freaks Forum.